# Take the color avarage of each column of a picture using OpenCV with C++ on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, pixel, iostream

I'm new using C++ and a need to compute the average of the red color in each column. Subsequently, I need to make a graph of the color density level per column.

This is the picture that i using, is a sample of a bone densitomery:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

FARPROC pGetPixel;

std::cout << "Medidas de muestra 1: \n";
Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Jimena G. Gordillo\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\den.bmp");

int matriz = img.cols * img.rows * 3;
const size_t chanels = 3; //RGB

//Lectura de cada pixel
for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++) {
    
        size_t p = y * img.cols * chanels + x * chanels; //
        uchar b = img.data[p + 0];
        uchar g = img.data[p + 1];
        uchar r = img.data[p + 2];

        for (int i = 0; i <= img.cols; i++) { //here is where I want to obtain the sum of each column
            int sum = sum + i;
        //Calculate average 
        long long average = sum / img.rows; // average is divided by the total of rows
        }
    }
}

cout << "Filas: " << img.rows<< endl;
cout << "Columnas: " << img.cols << endl;
cout << "Area: " << matriz << endl;

namedWindow("imagen", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("imagen", img);

waitKey(); 
return 0;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the problems you are currently facing implementing your solution? What's your current output vs your desired one? Can you elaborate about the graph you need to calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to check row by row not column by column also the third **for loop** is not needed.

Here is the solution for each channel(red,green,blue) columns average and graph of the column averages for each channel.

Source:

[image]

Red Channel Graph for each column average:

[image]

Green Channel Graph for each column average:

[image]

Blue Channel Graph for each column average:

[image]

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("/ur/source/image/directory/img.png");
    
    imshow("Source",img);
    
    long int avgRedChannel = 0,avgGreenChannel = 0, avgBlueChannel = 0;
    
    Mat graphRedChannel = Mat::zeros(Size(img.cols,300),CV_8UC1);
    Mat graphGreenChannel = Mat::zeros(Size(img.cols,300),CV_8UC1);
    Mat graphBlueChannel = Mat::zeros(Size(img.cols,300),CV_8UC1);
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
        {
            avgBlueChannel += (int)img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[0];
            avgGreenChannel += (int)img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[1];
            avgRedChannel += (int)img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j))[2];
        }
        graphBlueChannel.at<uchar>(Point(i,(avgBlueChannel/img.rows))) = 255;
        graphGreenChannel.at<uchar>(Point(i,(avgGreenChannel/img.rows))) = 255;
        graphRedChannel.at<uchar>(Point(i,(avgRedChannel/img.rows))) = 255;
        avgBlueChannel = 0;
        avgGreenChannel = 0;
        avgRedChannel = 0;
    }
    
    imshow("RedChannelGraph",graphRedChannel);
    imshow("GreenChannelGraph",graphGreenChannel);
    imshow("BlueChannelGraph",graphBlueChannel);
                        
    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, @YunusTemurlenk! Is helping me